# Windows vc++ websocket E_INVALID_PROTOCOL_FORMAT

Tags: c++, visual-c++, websocket

been making an app for work to automatically answer a call on my softphone when your hit your keyboard on the lock screen so i don't miss it when at the other end of the room.

I saw windows has web sockets, so i thought to use their one to prevent having to link libraries.

I have created a [websocket handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/websocket/nf-websocket-websocketcreateclienthandle).

```
if (WebSocketCreateClientHandle(NULL, 0, &socket_handle) != S_OK) {
    Log::LogMessage("WebSocketCreateClientHandle Failed", Log::LOGLEVEL::CRITICAL);
    return 1;
}
```

Then ran [WebSocketBeginClientHandshake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/websocket/nf-websocket-websocketbeginclienthandshake) .

```
// if handshake is successful, these will be populated
WEB_SOCKET_HTTP_HEADER* responceHeaders = nullptr;
ULONG responceHeadderCount;
if (WebSocketBeginClientHandshake(socket_handle, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &headers[0], 1, &responceHeaders, &responceHeadderCount) != S_OK) {
    return -1;
}
```

This returned S_OK. I then wrote out the array of headers like this:

```
// name nameLength, value valuelength
for (int i = 0; i < responceHeadderCount; i++) {
    std::cout << responceHeaders[i].pcName << "x" << responceHeaders[i].ulNameLength << ":" << responceHeaders[i].pcValue << "x" << responceHeaders[i].ulValueLength << std::endl;
}
```

which shows:

```
Sec-WebSocket-Keyx17:r7XbrevEUv6awqPe24f0Ww==┐å⌐≤w2x24
Connectionx10:Upgradex7
Upgradex7:websocketx9
Sec-WebSocket-Versionx21:13x2
```

I then pass these headers to [WebSocketEndClientHandshake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/websocket/nf-websocket-websocketendclienthandshake)  as well as some ULONG pointers:

```
ULONG selected_subprotocol;
ULONG selected_extensions;
ULONG selected_extensions_count;
HRESULT result = WebSocketEndClientHandshake(socket_handle, responceHeaders, responceHeadderCount, &selected_extensions, &selected_extensions_count, &selected_subprotocol);
```

The issue I have is [WebSocketEndClientHandshake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/websocket/nf-websocket-websocketendclienthandshake) . It always returns E_INVALID_PROTOCOL_FORMAT.

I modified my Host header to have the server address as nonsense"sdfkbsdf" to see what it does and low and behold nothing changes, BeginHandshake still succeeds and EndHandshake fails. so i am wondering if it is something to do with my Host header which is structured as follows:

```
WEB_SOCKET_HTTP_HEADER* host = new WEB_SOCKET_HTTP_HEADER;
PCHAR phost = (char*)"Host";
PCHAR pValue = (char*)"https://www.w3.org:80";
host->pcName = phost;
host->ulNameLength = sizeof(phost);
host->pcValue = pValue;
host->ulValueLength = sizeof(pValue);
headers.push_back(*host);
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong here?
I have tried adding my header to the array of headers returned by BeginClientHandshake and sending that to EndClientHandshake to see if that made a difference, no Luck.

Comment: You need to use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()` when assigning the `ulNameLength` and `ulValueLength` fields of `WEB_SOCKET_HTTP_HEADER`

Comment: Ah, thank for that, didn't fix the problem, but I have made that change.

Answer (score 1):

The WebSocket Protocol Component API provides:

> ... support for client and server handshake related HTTP headers, verifies received handshake data, and parses the WebSocket data stream. It does not handle any HTTP-specific operations (redirection, authentication, proxy support) nor perform any I/O operations (sending or receiving WebSocket stream bytes).

(from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/websock/web-socket-protocol-component-api-portal))

The API does not include transport, it needs HTTP to work. In order to do a handshake you would have to:

- Create an HTTP GET request to `ws://host.com:1234/path?q`
- Pass the request headers to `WebSocketBeginClientHandshake()`
- Add the returned additional headers to the request
- Send the request and receive the response (must be an `HTTP 101 Switching Protocols` response code)
- Pass the response headers to `WebSocketEndClientHandshake()` to get return code

You could use sockets or pipes as transport. For your use case it might be easier to just use the websocket functions of [WinHttp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-start-page), though.